# Creating specific Custom TListBoxItem with given example and trouble with fontColor property

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, delphi-xe4, tlistbox

[image]
Can someone please guide me in the right direction. I am attempting to create a Custom ListboxItem using Delphi XE4 for a iOS application. My goal output would be something along the lines of the photo above, where as I am currently stuck here (image below).

[image]

I have been successful at dynamically generating a ListBoxItem and inserting an TLabel object, however, I am unable to change the 'fontColor' property of the TLabel to a desired color. I can code

TLabel.Fontcolor := ClaBlue;

But the color reverts to black. I would ideal like it to look just like the example one I give. I am having troubles changing the font color of the inserted TLabel, and adding a gradient background to each Listbox Item. I do not know if I need to use a 'Style editor', or even how. And yes, I have looked at the sample included in Delphi/RAD Studio
Here is my current coding below:

```
while XMLNode<>nil do begin 

HeaderText := 'Part#: ' + XMLNode.ChildNodes['PARTNUM'].Text + Chr(9) + XMLNode.ChildNodes['VENDPARTNUM'].Text;

DetailText := '$' + XMLNode.ChildNodes['MD1_SELL_PRICE'].Text + ' /' + XMLNode.ChildNodes['UM1_PRICE_NAME'].Text + sLineBreak + 'Min: ' + XMLNode.ChildNodes['md2_from.MD2_MIN_QTY'].text + Chr(9) + 'On Hand: ' + XMLNode.ChildNodes['md2_from.MD2_ON_HAND_QTY'].text + Chr(9) + Label1.text ;
Form6.ListBox1.Items.Add(DetailText); 
ListBoxItem:=Form6.ListBox1.ListItems[Form6.ListBox1.Items.Count-1]; 
ListBoxItem.StyleLookup:='listboxitembottomdetail';
ListBoxItem.WordWrap:=True; 
ListBoxItem.Font.Size:= 8;
ListBoxItem.Height := 120; 
TestLabel := TLabel.Create(self); 
TestLabel.Text := HeaderText; 
TestLabel.font.size := 20; 
testLabel.FontColor := claBlue; 
TestLabel.Width := form6.ListBox1.ClientWidth;
i := i +1; 
XMLNode := XMLNode.NextSibling;
end; 
Form6.ListBox1.EndUpdate;
Form6.Show;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use the Style Book, 
use the **CustomListBox** sample that ships with delphi to learn how to properly use Styles in Firemonkey.

It also wouldn't hurt to read through some of the official Firemonkey style guides for introduction
 such as [Customizing FireMonkey Applications with Styles](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE4/en/Customizing_FireMonkey_Applications_with_Styles).

It looks more complicated then it is, in short to produce the result you want to :

1. Access the Style designer of the component
2. Via structure window edit/add/delete and modify controls, in your case it will be a combination of [TText](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE4/en/FMX.Objects.TText) Controls organized in [Tlayouts](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE4/en/WebComp.TLayout).
3. Once you've saved your modifications, you can change the color of a specific TText control at runtime: `Item.StylesData['TestLabel.Color'] := TAlphaColors.Red;` ( where Item is a TListboxitem )

What you are trying to achieve is not hard, learn handling the Style Designer via practice, pure trial and error, it's not as complicated as it looks.

Comment: For the most part, you are right. In addition to answer my question in more detail for others. I tooled around in the sample shipped with Xe4. In comparison to the article Peter notes, you do not access the Style Designer via right clicking a component in XE4, but rather just drop a TStyleBook component as a resource onto your desired Form. From there you work with the XML layout design.

Comment: Another speed bump**** I have actually gone with skipping the style book, and inserting TTexts dynamically as I did before with the Label. This time positioning them better, dynamically and also by using the tText, I was able to change the Ttext.fontcolor and have that color stick. Now, however, I can't seem to figure out how to implement a gradient background as I have in the desired example. Would it be best to insert a TcolorBox and set it to fill the parent, listboxItem or what ?

Comment: @JordanWeb, if you are inserting the Labels dynamically at runtime then you can basically solve your problem by creating a resource style book just like in the example and creating a new TLayout whos StyleName property is called itemGradient in which you put a TRectangle, set allClient and fill brush kind set to Gradient. When you create a new item simply add `Item.StyleLookup := 'ItemGradient';` just remember that the stylelookup string must match the name, it's very sensitive.

Comment: @PeterVonča Your solution can't be applied on FireMonkey Mobile, do you have any guideline?