# Can I change the color of a TListBox Selected Item?

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, tlistbox

I'm creating a multidevice FireMonkey application and I would like to change the color of a TListBox item when it is selected.
How can this be done in Rad Studio XE7?

Comment: [Creating specific Custom TListBoxItem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18411131/creating-specific-custom-tlistboxitem-with-given-example-and-trouble-with-fontco)

Comment: Which part of the task are you having trouble with?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1. Open **Bitmap Style Designer** (see a bin folder of RAD Studio) and create style by default for Android (**File -> New -> Android Light Style for FireMonkey**)
2. Expand node **"Images"** and make export all graphics resources.[image]
3. In any kind of graphics editor change color of background of **TListBoxItem**. [image]
4. Return to **BitmapStyleDesigner** and update each images (style.png, style20x.png, style15.png, style30x.png). For updating, select image node and click on "Update" button. [image]
5. Save style to file "File->Save as...->Выбираем тип файла "FireMonkey Style".
6. Put Style Book in a form and load this style.

Comment: As it stands the answer will likely be deleted as "very low quality" since it is a link only answer. You might make it a stand alone answer, keeping the link for reference.

Comment: Ok, i will rewrite it as standalone.

Answer (score -4):

Yes! It is possible in RAD Studio XE7 (answered before edit of question - please see revisions of question to understand what is being answered).

[Wink](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DuZPl.jpg)

Comment: You need to look into the Styles functionality of FireMonkey / FireUI